# Spring MVC resources not being mapped

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources

[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT0ZL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgnE9.png)

And my code in the JSP page is

```
<script src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/AppNameController.js'/>
```

I'm still getting 404 error

Comment: Thanks it worked,i was testing from the jsp files inside jsp folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the prefix set to `/WEB-INF/jsp` but looking at your project structure your *index.jsp* is only within the `/WEB-INF` folder rather than inside the `/WEB-INF/jsp` folder.

Also change to:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/scripts/AppNameController.js
```